# State machine that multiplies a binary number with a constant

Tags: finite-automata, transducers

I'm trying to create a FSM that multiplies a bitstream with a constant value (e.g 3).

I don't have a clue how to design such a FSM. Any hints?

Comment: What have you tried?  What approaches have you considered?  Have you tried working through some examples?  We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it.  e do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion.

Comment: I suggest you read http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755, read up on finite-state transducers, and read http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7879/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2745/755.

Comment: @D.W. So far I tried just to create a FSM for some possible input strings. But I got lost on the track. And I can't try every possible input string (eve though I hope there is some repetition). I think there needs to be an analytical approach but I couldn't come up with one yet. Yes, this is an homework question. No, I don't want a finished solution. I'm just stuck and need some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1 x_2 x_3 \cdots x_n$ denote the input string ($x_i$ is the $i$th bit of the input).  Let $y_1 y_2 y_3 \cdots y_n y_{n+1} y_{n+2}$ denote the desired output string ($y_i$ is the $i$th bit of the output).

You want a [finite-state transducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer) that, on input $x_1 \cdots x_n$, outputs $y_1 \cdots y_{n+2}$.

This is equivalent to asking for a deterministic finite-state machine (DFA) that accepts all strings of the form

$$x_1 y_1 x_2 y_2 x_3 y_3 \cdots x_{n-1} y_{n-1} x_n y_n E y_{n+1} E y_{n+2}$$

where $E$ is some special symbol that indicates "there's no more input" (end of the input).

There are [lots of resources](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755) on how to design a deterministic finite-state automaton (DFA) that accepts a particular language.  So, go use those resources to find a DFA that accepts that language.  Once you've done that, you will be able to translate it back to a finite-state transducer as required.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I read some of the stated resources. But still struggling. What if I have different input and output strings? (Basically I have infinite possible inputs) I tried again to do the FSM for some input strings. But I can't manage to do one that works with every possible input.

Comment: I finally managed to solve the exercise. But it was mostly by try-and-error. But thanks for all the hints!