# Converting from m base to n base without arithmetic operations (Where m<n )

Tags: turing-machines, pumping-lemma, base-conversion

I have been working the last 8 years in try to convert from base n to base m without artihmetical operations.

My hypothesis is that by the same way that is possible convert bases without division (see the tables bellow.) based in a literal conversion.

Can you create an equivalence table that allow this direct translation?

***Partial answer: No (After 10 years), by Pumping Lemma. ***

1. Numeric systems are a subset of regular languajes, therefore they follow the Pumping Lemma.
   (Pending demonstration)
2. Working in the update for Direct translation where:
   $$
     m = k·n | k ∈ N    
   $$

$$
     log_{(log_{n}(k))}n ∈ I
$$

3. Is possible numeric systems which their tokens represent real values instead of natural values?

-Working on the formal explanation-

$$   00011111_{2} $$
For converting from base *2* up to base *4* you have to get *pumping length*[1].
$$
  (Source Base)^x = (Destination Base)
$$

$$
  x = log_{sourceBase}(Destination Base) | x ∈ n
$$

$$
  2^x = 4
$$

$$
 x = 2
$$

---

And re create the new value representation based in the *finite alphabet transition table*[2] between the source and destination alphabets.

```
[01][11][11]| You don't need a math operation for this operation because
              The follow symbol '3'(4) -> '11'(2)
   [1][3][3]|
```

---

```
 [0011][111]| You don't need a math operation for this operation because
              The follow symbol
```

Transition Table from base 2 to base 8

$$
0_{8} = 000_{2}
$$

$$
1_{8} = 001_{2}
$$

$$
2_{8} = 010_{2}
$$
$$
3_{8} = 011_{2}
$$

$$
4_{8} = 100_{2}
$$

$$
5_{8} = 101_{2}
$$

$$
6_{8} = 110_{2}
$$

$$
7_{8} = 111_{2}
$$

$$
37_{8} = 133_{4} = 011111_{2}
$$

As it is very know the number of groups that you have to use is:

$$log_{n}=m $$ where ( n can be represented as m^c , and c is and Integer)
(m)

This operation:

```
'7'(8) -> '111'(2)   (Symbol(7)->111)
```

In my case, is a not math operations, because I have an state machine that is able to ***understand*** and *reflect* (bad joke) that symbol 7 means 111 in the default output (or default queue).

As you know when **c** is not an integer, we have a very complex problem therefore I was creating random table-states based on random rules (it means jumps of states using genetic algorithms) but It has been a real waste of time/energy.

Now I share my Idea, I believe that all bases must be represented as a sub-languages for other bases and they creates a cycle , It I couldn't  demostrate it as a formal theorem. But my heart, my soul and my migth believes that it could be possible.

For example:

```
(3) 0  1  2  / 10  11  12 20 / 
_______ 
3^1 (grp)  3^2(grp)
```

---

```
(2) 0  1  / 10  11  / 
_______ 
2^1 (grp)  2^2(grp)

(4) 0  1 2 3 / 10 11 12 13 20 21 22 23 30 31 32 33 / 
_______ 
4^1 (grp)  4^2(grp)

Conversion table:  
GroupSize = Log(2)^4
Rule: (0/0  1/1 2/10  3/11 )
_______________________________________________________
```

Do you have any formalism to define a base as *sub-language* of other base for cases like this?

Post In Edition.

[1]: Pumping Lemme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages

[2]: Transition Table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_table

Comment: (I find it hard to see *base conversion* when $m^k=n$.)

Comment: Yes, I have the follow problems : The alphabets always are discret number but is normal that logs have a non integer result this is my big obstacle to create a unified m -> n base conversion.

Comment: My other hypothesis is that exists a least common power, this is the philosophical stone, because is the size of the dictionary.

Comment: My take: $log_m n \in \mathbb{N}$ trivial, $log_m n \in \mathbb{I}$ no finite grammar, no TM.

Comment: This is part of the hypothesis, Sometimes I belive that it is as easy as synchronize 2 planets in the same point, each planet (base) after several cicles could to be in the same point in the same time again. Its like a least common multiple (LCM) but the cycles are exponentials.

Comment: It is easy enough to convert between bases 400 and 8000, but no rational exponent values beyond 0 will give the same result for bases 10 and 20.

Comment: May I ask, these 8 years, is this a hobby or an unhealthy obsession?

Comment: [Michal Konency](https://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/mkonecny/) studied in several papers ([this one](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(01)00095-0) may be the most relevant) which functions $[0,1]^n \to [0,1]$ can be computed with limited memory, say by a finite-state transducer. I think his work is relevant here, but I am not sure if this exact version was considered by him. You could alwyas ask him whether it is possible to implement in finite state the identity map if the input is in radix $b$ and the output is in radix $c$ representation (which is what you're doing).

Comment: BTW, just because Michal talks about maps between real numbers, that doesn't mean his work is irrelevant. The idea of computing with a finite-state automaton is exactly the idea of "having some lookup tables", but no counters, memory etc., in which one could "smuggle" some arithmetic.

Comment: Also related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/building-a-finite-state-transducer

Comment: And this is even more related, and has more answers: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254037670_Base_conversion_by_using_automata

Comment: Thanks a lot by the suggestions! the language of quantities can convert a periodic number, in according of its base, in to "fixed" value for other base, $$ 0.3333333333_{10} = 0.1_{3} $$ part of my study is "smuggle" irrational values using other bases. Because the big problem is the arithmetic, even we, the humans, are not able to sum values, We use rules to jump from a value to other value using memory-based rules to implement mathematical operations such as sum or subtraction.

Comment: And part of the study is to create an algortihm/equation to create the maps.